# Response before coroutine resolved, kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Hello stack**overflow**!
I am writing a little service web app that accepts data for sending an email using spring boot kotlin. My question is how to make controller respond instantly after a request received and send the actual email in the background thread. Firstly controller sends the email then publishes message on rabbitMQ and only after that returns respond as a specified string.

```
@RestController
class MailController(private val emailService: EmailService, private val msgSender: CustomMessageSender) {

@PostMapping("/api/sendemail")
suspend fun sendEmail(@RequestBody request: Email): String {
    coroutineScope {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                emailService.sendMail(request.to, request.subject!!, request.msg)
                delay(2000)
                msgSender.sendMessage()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        }
    }
    return "email queued"
}
```

}

Comment: this should have worked. try `async` instead of `launch`

Comment: @sidgate no it is not supposed to work with `coroutineScope`, because this function waits until child coroutines are done before resuming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this kind of requirement, you need to understand `CoroutineScope`s.
Scopes limit the lifetime of a coroutine.

When you use `coroutineScope { ... }`, you define a scope that will end at the end of the block. Meaning, all child coroutines started inside of it must have completed or have been cancelled before this function can resume. In other words, `coroutineScope` will suspend the current coroutine until all child coroutines are done, which is not what you want here, because then you won't return until the email is sent.

> Side note: this is actually why `coroutineScope` is suspending. It's actually the suspending equivalent of `runBlocking`, which on the other hand *blocks* the current thread while waiting for child coroutines.

What you need is a scope bigger than your function body. One dirty way to do this is to use the `GlobalScope` (which has the same lifetime as your application). A better way to do this would be to define a coroutine scope tied to the lifecycle of your Spring component, so that if your component is destroyed, the coroutines launched by it are cancelled.

One way to do the above is to define a scope like this:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy

@RestController
class MailController(
    private val emailService: EmailService,
    private val msgSender: CustomMessageSender
) {
    // use a regular Job() if you want all coroutines to be cancelled if one fails
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

    // this method is NOT suspending anymore, because it doesn't call
    // suspending functions directly, it just starts a coroutine.
    @PostMapping("/api/sendemail")
    fun sendEmail(@RequestBody request: Email): String {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                emailService.sendMail(request.to, request.subject!!, request.msg)
                delay(2000)
                msgSender.sendMessage()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        }
        return "email queued"
    }
    

    @PreDestroy
    fun cancelScope() {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

If your component always lives as long as your application anyway, you may also define your custom scope at application level, and inject it here (without the cancellation in `@PreDestroy`). `GlobalScope` is still not a great idea in this case because it prevents you from centrally changing elements of the coroutine context for your "global" coroutines. Having an application scope allows you, for instance, to add an exception handler, change the thread pool, or give coroutine names.

Comment: May i know why its better to create custom-scope tied to the life cycle of spring bean (private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())), the rest-controller in this case, especially when they are stereo-typed singletons ? I have a similar requirement but I'm creating custom-scope that is method local.

Comment: @V1666 What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to launch one or more coroutines but wait for them before your method returns a result, you should use `coroutineScope { ... }`. If you want to launch a coroutine that lives longer than your method call, you have to decide how long it's supposed to live. If the code inside the coroutine is not well behaved and hangs, when is it supposed to be cancelled? When do you stop being interested in this coroutine? The answer to these questions is materialized by how you define and cancel your coroutine scope

Comment: I tried to be general in the approach, hence the "good practice" of cancelling the scope at the end of the lifecycle of your component. But as I said at the end of the answer, if your component is a Spring singleton anyway, you may as well use an application-wide scope that is never canceled. It's just better if you can define a scope as small as possible. Creating throw-away scopes inside your function call is not good practice, though, because they would be virtually endless, even though they are declared locally. This is technically leaking uncontrolled coroutines.

Comment: My requirement is to make the sub-coroutines work as fire-and-forget tasks - basically make them work as some sort of runnables when executed with executorService. Instead, we are going the coroutine route. Well, its kinda agreeable to tie the coroutines to some scope tied up to a spring-service-bean (singleton) but such a scope will only be destroyed when the application goes down i suppose ? Since its a scope coming from a service-impl bean, there would be many-many child coroutines associated with the class-level scope. Cancelling all of them might not be desirable ?

Comment: Posted new follow-up qsn here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897544/springboot-coroutine-bean-scope-or-local-scope